# filters is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Hey guys am trying to rotate and image in IE 8 using the following filters

so i have this function which sets the angle

```
var setElementAngle=function(ele,ang){
    var angle = Math.PI / ang;

    costheta = Math.cos(angle);
    sintheta = Math.sin(angle);

    ele.filters.item(0).M11 = costheta;
    ele.filters.item(0).M12 = -sintheta;
    ele.filters.item(0).M21 = sintheta;
    ele.filters.item(0).M22 = costheta;
};
```

initally  i create an img element using the function below

```
var create =function (el, attr, style) {
        this.elem = document.createElement(el);
        for (var k in attr) {
            if (attr.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                this.elem.setAttribute(k, attr[k])
            }
        }
        for (var k in style) {
            if (style.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                this.elem.style[k] = style[k]
            }
        }
        return this.elem
 };

       var _img=create('img',
{'id':'_img','width':'50','height':'53','border':'0','src':'10fqnav.jpg'},
{'position':'absolute',
 'height':'53px',
 'width':'50px',
 'zIndex':'9001',
 'top':'0px',
 'right':'0px',
 'display':'inline-block',
 'filter':'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod=\'auto expand\')'
 });
```

then later in my code i change  the image src attribute and then try rotating it

```
   $('#_img').attr('src','fold_new.jpg');
   setElementAngle(_img,0.45);
```

at this point i get the following error

```
   Message: 'filters' is null or not an object
```

Any idea what could be the reason. also am setting the filter initally.

Comment: @cookiemonster so any other way i can rotate image in IE 8 . i should be able to rotate it any specified angle

Comment: create fiddle for better answer.

Answer (score 0):

`_img` most likely doesn't point to the image in the HTML in your call to

```
setElementAngle(_img,0.45);
```

Try changing that to

```
setElementAngle($('#_img'),0.45);
```

I'm guessing that the copy in memory (i.e. `_img`) doesn't "have layout" until it's actually in the DOM and must be accessed there.